# How can I create a Outlook mail draft via MAPI from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, email, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

Is there a code example available on the web which helps me getting started with mail creation (including a recipient list) with Delphi and Outlook? Currently we use mailto: however this has a limitation regarding the URL length, and we need a way to put quite many users on the recipient list. (No this is will not be a spam mail application). We can not use SMTP because the user needs to display and edit the draft before sending.

I have found some hints about WebDAV, maybe this is another option (using MS Exchange 2008)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://www.rapware.nl/prod_easymapi_page1.asp?SubMenu=EasyMAPI.

Its a really good component, I have been using it for a long time with great results. It supports MS Exchange as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the suggestion(s) so far! I have also found an article about OLE (instead of MAPI). I will test it as soon as possible, with Outlook 2010.

[Sending an email from Delphi with Outlook](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/network/f517.shtml)

> "Outlook can be easily controlled
>   through OLE. Try the sample procedure
>   SendOutlookMail() from below. This
>   does not work with Outlook Express"